# Bouncy Castle NoSuchAlgorithm Exception, but Provider Installed

Tags: java, bouncycastle, encryption

I am trying to use Bouncy Castle to do some RSA encryption/decryption. While everything works-ish, I'm getting corrupted output in my decryption function. I assume this is due to the lack of proper padding when calling the algorithm.

I've installed Bouncy Castle by adding it (bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar) to my classpath and installing it in my constructor like so:

```
Security.addProvider( new BouncyCastleProvider() );
```

To verify that the provider is installed, I have called:

```
if (Security.getProvider( "BC" ) != null)
{
      System.out.println( "Bouncy Castle provider is available" );
}
```

Which works as expected.

When getting my cipher, I get ciphertext and the corrupted clear text when I try to use algorithm "RSA". I understand that I need to use an algorithm with padding, such as PKCS or others, but the following attempt to get the cipher fails with a NoSuchAlgorithm exception:

```
Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding", "BC");
```

Regardless of the others I try, the only way I can get a cipher is if I call:

```
Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
```

Why would the PKCS cipher not be available? I have installed the unlimited jurisdiction policy and, as I said, the plain "RSA" works, but the padding call does not. Further, I've tried to list out the Bouncy Castle keys in the provider and it looks like a pretty exhaustive list.

Can anyone helpe me sort out why this is missing?

Thanks! Evan

Comment: works for me, I think you are leaving some important details out. Why don't you post the stack trace. Also, you don't need bouncycastle for this.

Comment: @GregS  thanks for the response. Here's the stack trace:  
`Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: RSA/PKCS1PADDING for provider BC
 at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:70)
 at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:190)
 at java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance(KeyFactory.java:181)
 at com.configurator.StandardConfigurator.readKeyFromFile(StandardConfigurator.java:124)
 ... 2 more`

Comment: I thought that I needed Bouncy Castle for the RSA implementations that include padding? Also, I was hoping to eliminate any sort of ambiguity between systems and implementations, as this is distributed code.

Comment: That stack trace suggests that code you posted does *not* correspond to the code that caused the stack trace. It is as if the code that is actually running used `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/PKCS1PADDING");`

Comment: Hey Greg, that's correct. When using **ANY** padding algorithms ("RSA/PKCS1PADDING" or "RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding" or any other) I get the exception. "RSA" is the only one that comes back with a cipher. Unfortunately, I need the padding algorithm to handle encryption.

Comment: Well, I don't get an exception when I use "RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding". The middle part of the spec is not the padding, it is the mode. It has to be there but for RSA it is ignored.

Comment: Trying that, I still get the NoSuchAlgorithmException: `Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding for provider BC
 at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 ... 2 more`

Comment: And I'm a total idiot. @Greg, you were correct, it wasn't exactly related. I had put the Algorithm in an external variable and the exception was being thrown while building the KeySpec! Thanks for helping me work through this and I really appreciate  your help!

Comment: glad you solved your problem.